# Multi level grouping with JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Below is my Json ARRAY:

```
var person = [ { name: 'Jim', color: 'blue', Office:'Microsoft', age: 22, }, { name: 'Sam', color: 'blue', Office:'Microsoft', age: 33, }, { name: 'Eddie', color: 'green', Office:'Dell', age: 77, }, ]
```

I was able to get the single group by functionality working by using the below function

```
var  GroupByResults= person.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.color] = r[a.color] || [];
        r[a.color].push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
```

i got the below output

```
{ "blue": [ { "name": "Jim", "color": "blue", Office:'Microsoft', "age": 22 }, { "name": "Sam", "color": "blue", Office:'Microsoft', "age": 33 } ], "green": [ { "name": "Eddie", "color": "green", Office:'Dell', "age": 77 } ] }
```

How can i acheive multi level grouping?? I want another group by with Office so first group by with color and next group with office Can any one help me ...

Comment: could you add an example of the desired output to the opening post?

Comment: have you tried replacing **a.color** with **a.Office**?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a function for the group building, something like:

```js
const data = [{ name: 'Jim', color: 'blue', Office:'Microsoft', age: 22, }, { name: 'Sam', color: 'blue', Office:'Microsoft', age: 33, }, { name: 'Eddie', color: 'green', Office:'Dell', age: 77, }]

function generateGroup(data, key) {
  return data.reduce((r, a) => {
    r[a[key]] = r[a[key]] || [];
    r[a[key]].push(a);
    return r;
  }, {});
}

const KEYS = ['name', 'color', 'Office', 'age'];

const result = [];
for (const k of KEYS) {
  result.push(generateGroup(data, k));
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `forEach` of each key of your objects, with that you can group using all the keys at the same time.

you will get something like:

```
{
    "name": [
        {
            "name": "Jim",
            "color": "blue",
            "Office": "Microsoft",
            "age": 22
        },
        {
            "name": "Sam",
            "color": "blue",
            "Office": "Microsoft",
            "age": 33
        },
        {
            "name": "Eddie",
            "color": "green",
            "Office": "Dell",
            "age": 77
        }
    ],
    "color": [
        {
            "name": "Jim",
            "color": "blue",
            "Office": "Microsoft",
            "age": 22
        },
        {
            "name": "Sam",
            "color": "blue",
            "Office": "Microsoft",
            "age": 33
        },
        {
            "name": "Eddie",
            "color": "green",
            "Office": "Dell",
            "age": 77
        }
    ],
    "Office": [
        {
            "name": "Jim",
            "color": "blue",
            "Office": "Microsoft",
            "age": 22
        },
        {
            "name": "Sam",
            "color": "blue",
            "Office": "Microsoft",
            "age": 33
        },
        {
            "name": "Eddie",
            "color": "green",
            "Office": "Dell",
            "age": 77
        }
    ],
    "age": [
        {
            "name": "Jim",
            "color": "blue",
            "Office": "Microsoft",
            "age": 22
        },
        {
            "name": "Sam",
            "color": "blue",
            "Office": "Microsoft",
            "age": 33
        },
        {
            "name": "Eddie",
            "color": "green",
            "Office": "Dell",
            "age": 77
        }
    ]
}
```

note: dismiss the `JSON.stringify` function, it is only to show the result in a readable way.

```js
var person = [{
  name: 'Jim',
  color: 'blue',
  Office: 'Microsoft',
  age: 22,
}, {
  name: 'Sam',
  color: 'blue',
  Office: 'Microsoft',
  age: 33,
}, {
  name: 'Eddie',
  color: 'green',
  Office: 'Dell',
  age: 77,
}, ]

var GroupByResults = person.reduce(function(r, a) {
  const keys = Object.keys(a);

  keys.forEach(k => {
    r[k] = r[k] || [];
    r[k].push(a);
  })


  return r;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(JSON.stringify(GroupByResults, null, 4));
```